# AWS S3 cannot delete objects in bucket via PHP SDK

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm using AWS SDK for PHP (Laravel) and I'm trying to delete a S3 bucket with all the objects inside. Here is my code:

```
public function deleteBucket($syndcateid){
    $s3client = AWS::createClient('s3');
    $bucket = env('S3_BUCKET')."/syndcate-uploads/syndcate-".$syndcateid;
    $listObjectsParams = ['Bucket' => $bucket];
    $batchDelete = BatchDelete::fromListObjects($s3client, $listObjectsParams);
    $batchDelete->delete();
    $s3client->deleteBucket(array('Bucket' => $bucket));
    $s3client->waitUntil('BucketNotExists', array('Bucket' => $bucket));
}
```

And when I run this code, I get the error:

> Error executing \"ListObjects\" on \"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/syndcate-media%2Fsyndcate-uploads%2Fsyndcate-32?delimiter=%2F&encoding-type=url\"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `GET https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/syndcate-media%2Fsyndcate-uploads%2Fsyndcate-32?delimiter=%2F&encoding-type=url` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:\n\n`SignatureDoesNotMatch`The request signature we calcul (truncated...)\n SignatureDoesNotMatch (client): The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. - \n`SignatureDoesNotMatch`The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

Basically it is a `SignatureDoesNotMatch` error, and the reason its happening is, the slashes in the URL are not being decoded, as the requested URL (`https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/syndcate-media%2Fsyndcate-uploads%2Fsyndcate-32`) appears to have `%2F` instead of slashes.

I tried with the root bucket (no slashes), and it worked.

Any idea how to get the bucket name right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it!

What was I thinking, the bucket is only `env('S3_BUCKET')`, that is sort of the root. But there are no folders in S3, there is a folder-like structure to make classification easier. All files are in one place, the filenames has paths as the prefix (ie. `/path/to/folder/image.jpg`).

So I want wasn't deleting a bucket, but only deleting a folder. But since there are no folders, I only wanted to delete the files that stars with a prefix such as `path/to/folder/`

Anyways, here is the updated code:

```
public function deleteBucket($syndcateid){
        $s3client = AWS::createClient('s3');
        $startsWith = "syndcate-uploads/syndcate-".$syndcateid."/";
        $listObjectsParams = ['Bucket' => env('S3_BUCKET'), 'Prefix'=>$startsWith, 'Delimiter'=>'/'];
        $batchDelete = BatchDelete::fromListObjects($s3client, $listObjectsParams);
        $batchDelete->delete();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

ya S3 is an object store so no actual folders.